# Is it possible to see where control focus is being lost to?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a `ClistCtrl` (wraps Windows list view for non-MFC users) on a dialog. I set functionality that when the list loses focus, any selected items are unselected.

I also have a "remove items" button, whose on-click handler will delete any selected items in the list.

The idea is you select items in the list, and then either click the button to remove these items, or click somewhere else and the selection is cancelled.

*But*, when you click the delete button, the list loses focus *first* and therefore nothing happens! Is there a way around this?

Comment: `WM_KILLFOCUS` tells you which window the input focus is moving to

Comment: @DavidHeffernan To catch this in the context of a CDialog with controls, would I have to implement `PreTranslateMessage` or something? A code sample would be really great in an answer, I always forget what I can and can't add event notifiers for in my message-map.

Comment: Websearch will show you how

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it hasn't so far. That's why I asked. I just get a mess of results tangentially resulted... probably my search term is not great.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was nothing already out there that shows how to catch a windows message in an MFC app. Seems implausible.

Comment: i think your approach of focus and no focus is completely wrong, you have to handle OnItemClick() instead and store selected items ids in an array for example. a click select the items the next click unselect it. this is of course just an Opinion

Answer (score 2):

You can receive message about lost focus with [WM_KILLFOCUS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/ms646282(v=vs.85).aspx), its wParam will give you a handle to window which got focus:

> wParam
>
> A handle to the window that receives the keyboard focus. This
>   parameter can be NULL.

You should be able to use Spy++ to see WM_KILLFOCUS on you list window, and read its wParam - and later find also with spy++ which window is it.

Comment: Is this also compatible with `ON_NOTIFY(NM_KILLFOCUS,...)`? Or perhaps I should ask, what would code look like in MFC - am I catching `WM_KILLFOCUS` on the dialog and checking the control IDs, or setting a handler on the specific control?

Comment: Yes `ON_NOTIFY(NM_KILLFOCUS,` should work if you want to receive message for given control in your dialog function.

Comment: The thing is, I can't see where I find the window gaining focus (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) A [pseudo] code example would make your answer more complete?

Comment: You are right this is cant be done with notifications, you will have to subclass your list control. Maybe some one else will suggest how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with that, just hoped I wouldn't have to go to the trouble. I cannot catch/intercept/inspect the per-control messages from the dialog then, e.g. override `CWnd::PreTranslateMessage()`?

Comment: @Mr.Boy I dont think you can do it

Answer (score 2):

As said in other posts, you can use `WM_KILLFOCUS` for that.

But I think it's *a very bad idea* to clear the selection on losing focus.

Just imagine: the user selects a whole bunch of items using multiselect (using shift, ctrl, scrollbar..), and then, one of the following happens:

- The phone rings, urgent call - the user needs to check a mail: selection: gone!
- An annoying message box pops up taking focus (yes, it does happen): selection -> gone.

Your users might hate you for this, so don't do it :) (not even if there are only 3 items in the listcontrol).

The usual way is to gray the selection on losing focus. You could add a 'clear selection' button, but even that isn't needed. Just clicking on one item will clear the selection (except for that one item of course).

Bottom line: don't clear the selection on losing focus, ever.

**Update**:

If the selection is not visible on losing focus, the `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS` flag is what you need:

> [`LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739.aspx)
>
> The selection, if any, is always shown, even if the control does not
>   have the focus.

Comment: Well, when focus is lost you cannot see what the selection _is_ any more. So now you select some items, click on a different control and have no idea what will happen when you click the delete button.

Comment: @Mr.Boy - Well, that should be fixed first then. Are you using ClistCtrl in a standard way, or user/custom/owner drawn? The usual way is to gray the selection on losing focus. In your case you could control that from the Dialog maybe: gray when dialog loses focus, set to selection color again when the dialog gets focus (because the user can't click inside the list, because that would clear the selection too).

Comment: @Mr.Boy - Check out `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS` for this (see my updated answer for more details).

Comment: See my related question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945788/always-show-selection-doesnt-work-on-clistctrl?rq=1) for some reason, this doesn't seem to work with text items, only icons.

Comment: That would be strange.. I'll try to write a small test later on (I usually use ClistCtrl in report mode, and this works fine). Another way to fix this would be to use custom draw or owner draw. Than you have full control.

Comment: See my comment on that question ;)

Comment: For what it's worth, I do agree with your main argument. But it seems I need a work-around and in this case I don't think the annoyance would be too significant.

Comment: @Mr.Boy - _"in this case I don't think the annoyance would be too significant."_. Yes, that's how it all starts.. just don't do it :) I Tested it here, works great with `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS`. But if nothing else helps, you could also have a look at [custom draw](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra), which gives you full control over the colors.